# How to do basic AEAD encryption in Node.js

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to implement basic encryption functionality in my node app. The problem is that almost all of the examples and guides that I have found (including those on the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher)) use non-authenticated ciphers.

So, I hoping someone can take a look at what I have and let me know if I'm doing something stupid or leaving myself open to any obvious side-channel attacks.

When I run this code everything works as expected (i.e. test that are supposed to pass do, and those that are supposed to fail do) except in one case.

It seems that I can append an arbitrary amount of data to the end of the cipher text and the message still decrypts without error. I thought an authenticated encryption system is supposed to fail when there is any modification to the cipher text. You can test this by changing the `tweakCharAt` variable to something big like 100. Did I do something wrong? Is this somehow expected behavior?

```js
const { createCipheriv, createDecipheriv, randomBytes, randomFillSync } = require('crypto');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const randomBytesPromise = promisify(randomBytes);

const algorithm = 'chacha20-poly1305';
const ivLen = 12; // IETF version of ChaCha20-Poly1305 uses a 96 bit (12 byte) nonce
const authTagLength = 16; // Poly1305 generates a 128 bit (16 byte) authentication tag

// Takes a Node Transform stream (like Cipher and Decipher) + some data and returns a Promise
const streamPromise = (stream, data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Create an array to hold the chunks of binary data
    const chunks = [];

    // Setup stream event handlers
    // See: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher
    stream.on('readable', () => {
        let chunk;

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-cond-assign
        while ((chunk = stream.read()) !== null) {

            chunks.push(chunk);
        }
    });

    stream.on('end', () => { resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)); });

    stream.on('error', (error) => { reject(error); });

    // Write the given data to the stream and then close it up
    stream.write(data);
    stream.end();
});

const encrypt = (plainText, key, authenticatedData = Buffer.alloc(0)) => (

    randomBytesPromise(ivLen)
        .then((rand) => {

            const iv = rand;

            const cipher = createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv, { authTagLength });

            cipher.setAAD(authenticatedData);

            return streamPromise(cipher, plainText)
                .then(encMessage => [iv, authenticatedData, cipher.getAuthTag(), encMessage]);
        })
        .then(parts => parts.map(buffer => buffer.toString('base64')).join(':'))
);

const decrypt = (cipherText, key) => {

    const [
        iv,
        authenticatedData,
        authTag,
        message
    ] = cipherText.split(':').map(string => Buffer.from(string, 'base64'));

    const decipher = createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv, { authTagLength });

    decipher.setAAD(authenticatedData);
    decipher.setAuthTag(authTag);

    return streamPromise(decipher, message);
};

const test = (message, keyBuffer, authenticatedData, testNum, tamperWithCipherText = false) => (

    encrypt(message, keyBuffer, authenticatedData)
        .then((cipherText) => {

            console.log(testNum + ' cipher text:     ', cipherText);

            let newCipherText = cipherText;

            if (tamperWithCipherText) {

                const tweakCharAt = 30; // 100;

                newCipherText = newCipherText.substring(0, tweakCharAt)
                    + '0' // '==/I5QUaGV'
                    + newCipherText.substring(tweakCharAt + 1);

                console.log(testNum + ' new cipher text: ', newCipherText);
            }

            console.log(testNum + ' AAD:             ', Buffer.from(newCipherText.split(':')[1], 'base64').toString('utf8'));

            return decrypt(newCipherText, keyBuffer);
        })
        .then((plainText) => {

            console.log(testNum + ' plain text:      ', plainText.toString('utf8') + '\n');
        })
        .catch((error) => {

            console.error(testNum, error);
        })
);

// Run some tests
const key = Buffer.allocUnsafe(32);
randomFillSync(key);
const testMessage = 'Top secret message';
const authData = Buffer.from('AAD data here', 'utf8');

// Test without authenticated data
test(testMessage, key, undefined, 1); // should work
test(testMessage, key, undefined, 2, true); // should error

// Test with authenticated data
test(testMessage, key, authData, 3); // should work
test(testMessage, key, authData, 4, true); // should error
```

## Sample Output

Here is some output from running the above code in Node 12 with different settings for where to modify the cipher text.

### Modify a character in the middle (detected)

```
1 cipher text:      /mFoBKirqH8DZ3Wv::JayX8aiYi77ApLyhI6yYfw==:uBOj318Zf9M2qaBgIkiEX2MC
1 AAD:
1 plain text:       Top secret message

2 cipher text:      QnEbbrFpYhTLPuhk::owdqDGokK9WoXE0Od5DDTQ==:QROQ3/Q1qhKz4/FSQbwFuVoG
2 new cipher text:  QnEbbrFpYhTLPuhk::owdqDGokK9Wo0E0Od5DDTQ==:QROQ3/Q1qhKz4/FSQbwFuVoG
2 AAD:
2 Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
    at Decipheriv._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:144:29)
    at Decipheriv.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:140:10)
    at Decipheriv.emit (events.js:200:13)
    ...
3 cipher text:      36cf2xXpsZnfFn+I:QUFEIGRhdGEgaGVyZQ==:NRRNaY9yAJ2yu7z4Nh0+Tw==:ZdY9xtFh0zcXgDcydG+zEhug
3 AAD:              AAD data here
3 plain text:       Top secret message

4 cipher text:      HWA0BWBPHe/3kFps:QUFEIGRhdGEgaGVyZQ==:w6s+CYMeU0SNoCtgbeRBsw==:2TOwGnbT2T1ZZ8qKe90BU2VJ
4 new cipher text:  HWA0BWBPHe/3kFps:QUFEIGRhdGEga0VyZQ==:w6s+CYMeU0SNoCtgbeRBsw==:2TOwGnbT2T1ZZ8qKe90BU2VJ
4 AAD:              AAD data kEre
4 Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
    at Decipheriv._flush (internal/crypto/cipher.js:144:29)
    at Decipheriv.prefinish (_stream_transform.js:140:10)
    at Decipheriv.emit (events.js:200:13)
    ...
```

### Add to end, base64 (not detected)

```
1 cipher text:      cwtqwgX2mB5gmPh4::I2yPh0xoorrvVU+7edM1Ww==:V9qnpa25HEPw/v6zBc03tpYz
1 AAD:
1 plain text:       Top secret message

2 cipher text:      fe4spIYdiJDyIaUo::unK0AA6vI9bTDDVN/qm3Gw==:dE9bRpOi99ntKviitH4QdkGR
2 new cipher text:  fe4spIYdiJDyIaUo::unK0AA6vI9bTDDVN/qm3Gw==:dE9bRpOi99ntKviitH4QdkGRA
2 AAD:
2 plain text:       Top secret message

3 cipher text:      zzDP/FB3u4svhDoC:QUFEIGRhdGEgaGVyZQ==:GExIqrogg8Dm8ifQUhVxJg==:VH46trhHXsmcafPdImgArorb
3 AAD:              AAD data here
3 plain text:       Top secret message

4 cipher text:      TQE0QC8wUAElPYIC:QUFEIGRhdGEgaGVyZQ==:TpWkCLskrnRrQOykke+FoA==:YF3WEywHVzPNzuTg7UYKD3Ja
4 new cipher text:  TQE0QC8wUAElPYIC:QUFEIGRhdGEgaGVyZQ==:TpWkCLskrnRrQOykke+FoA==:YF3WEywHVzPNzuTg7UYKD3JaA
4 AAD:              AAD data here
4 plain text:       Top secret message
```

### Add to end, hex (not detected)

```
1 cipher text:      35ddfd0541be72780793894b::dc9ea755fbf00ee1bd9b737727b912af:5cd46cad985c2da058fa51967a675cb9bda6
1 AAD:
1 plain text:       Top secret message

2 cipher text:      0da4c80d45610cd3717e8497::0fcdea1d4ccfb9cb4347491430ccc4b3:3060d55728bc8ab2f75f80ce27ebe06f813e
2 new cipher text:  0da4c80d45610cd3717e8497::0fcdea1d4ccfb9cb4347491430ccc4b3:3060d55728bc8ab2f75f80ce27ebe06f813eA
2 AAD:
2 plain text:       Top secret message

3 cipher text:      f6ae6d9a72139b8611dd3798:41414420646174612068657265:f00d9d987f94038334603165605ce966:c6e635d8d81da0badd0ee98d64e007308853
3 AAD:              AAD data here
3 plain text:       Top secret message

4 cipher text:      a66fab00b07bc963cff3c721:41414420646174612068657265:05ed29d50a426df3b5a3616c7a467703:1b9d88bfdff01f5eacad9ce7cd9a117d6b08
4 new cipher text:  a66fab00b07bc963cff3c721:41414420646174612068657265:05ed29d50a426df3b5a3616c7a467703:1b9d88bfdff01f5eacad9ce7cd9a117d6b08A
4 AAD:              AAD data here
4 plain text:       Top secret message
```

Comment: I see you base64 encode your encrypted data .. do you paste the data after a base64 termination char: '=' ? If so, the base64 decoder would properbly just ignore this addition data ..

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. I did some more testing, and I can append at will if I start the addition with an `=`, but I can still append one character otherwise. I'll update the question to include some sample output from the program, so you can see what I'm talking about. I'm also seeing the same behavior when I use hex encoding instead of base64.